# gmusicbrowser doesn't start?

Tags: gmusicbrowser

`gmusicbrowser` doesn't start. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64bits. In the terminal, I get the following error:

```
$ gmusicbrowser
print() on closed filehandle $fifofh at /usr/bin/gmusicbrowser line 328.
GStreamer::Interfaces perl module not found -> visuals not available
Reading saved tags in ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc ...
Can't read '~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc', aborting...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I use the same player. [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gmbrc` is corrupted. Try a backup, you have several backups in `~/.config/gmusicbrowser`

*Sample output*

```
% ls -og ~/.config/gmusicbrowser
insgesamt 34588
-rw-rw-r-- 1 12943689 Jul  5 19:33 gmbrc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 12943689 Jul  4 22:24 gmbrc.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1893728 Mai  6 14:54 gmbrc.bak.20150506.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1894384 Mai  7 09:34 gmbrc.bak.20150507.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1895944 Mai  8 14:49 gmbrc.bak.20150508.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1900908 Mai 19 10:17 gmbrc.bak.20150519.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1923200 Jul  4 14:49 gmbrc.bak.20150704.xz
```

Open a terminal and do the following:

```
mv ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc.xxx
cp ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc.bak ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc
```

After that, start `gmusicbrowser` again.

---

If all this does not work, then you will need to delete `~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc` and start over. Sorry **:\**

But as little bonus, here is a daily build [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~andreas-boettger/+archive/ubuntu/gmusicbrowser-daily).

[image]

<sub>gmusicbrowser in action with some [additionally layouts](https://launchpad.net/~andreas-boettger/+archive/ubuntu/gmusicbrowser-art)</sub>

Comment: @becko Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: I actually removed this folder and still the problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

Try running `touch ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc` in terminal. If you get an error about the file already existing try this: `sudo chown $USER ~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc`

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.

Comment: Oh well... :( I tried